# Is it appropriate to request a bottle of wine at the table upon arrival at a dinner reservation?

Tags: wine, pairing

I'm making reservations at a nice place on the bay where I'm going to go on a date. I'm at the point in the online reservation where I can write requests in a text field. Is it appropriate to request wine at the table upon arrival? I want to make it seem like I am beyond prepared for this date.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to order the wine ahead of time? It might make more sense to wait until you select your food so that the wine pairs appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is it appropriate to request a bottle of wine at the table upon arrival at a dinner reservation?**

Absolutely, but make sure your guest would be comfortable with your intended instructions to the particular restaurant of your choice. Your setting the mood in a rather noble way.

Make sure that such would not offended your dinner guest and make sure you know the wine varieties preferred of your intended date.

Wine is supposed to relax people. So why not do the ordering ahead of time, especially wine in a public space!

Also make sure your wine will pair as close as possible with the intended meal that is to be served.

Answer (score 3):

I think the restaurant will be fine with it (hospitality staff are used to dealing with far more unusual requests than this); the question is really what your date will think, which is perhaps more of an [interpersonal skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) question.

How about asking for some good sparkling wine? You won't know what wine you want to have with the meal until you've chosen dishes, but a bit of bubbly beforehand is universally compatible! Champagne is the traditional choice to impress, Prosecco is more relaxed and fun, Cava, to me, has an unfair image of being a cheapskate's champagne, English sparkling wine marks you out as an innovator (or eccentric), and there are many others.

You could ask for a glass each to be brought to the table the moment you arrive, or for there to be a bottle waiting for you on ice. I would ask for a half-bottle - a whole bottle would be a lot to get through before your starter, unless you are dating Winston Churchill.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely inappropriate.  Restaurants are part of the service industry, and love to please customers.  Typical advance requests often include preferred seating locations, flowers, notable special occasions, etc.

Requesting wine prior to the meal is unusual, however, and if it's an upscale restaurant, part of the service is bringing the wine to the table and opening it for you, having you taste it, etc. Requesting a "pour it yourself" bottle could possibly be awkward.

If you truly want to impress, visit the restaurant ahead of time, ask to speak to the Sommelier, and offer a significant tip in advance with the details of your reservation, and have him/her meet you upon arrival to provide the requested bottle.

Alternately, investigate the restaurant's corkage fee, and find a wine you want to bring yourself, letting the Somm open it, decant it, and pour it for you.

Comment: A much better answer.